# IIS shared filed path

Tags: iis, umbraco

**My scenario**

I have created an Umbraco Site but when I am giving it a folder's path, i.e. to a Shared Folder, it's giving me the following error:

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x80070003
Config Error       Cannot read configuration file
Config File    \\?\X:\MyProject\web.config
Requested URL      http://10.0.0.5:80/
Physical Path      
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
```

I have tried all possible solutions, i.e. IIS USER permission, application pool etc

I would like to know how IIS can read the `web.config` file path from a Shared Folder. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use network share in the IIS physical path, open up IIS, click on website, and under Advanced Settings change the physical path to the network share. also you may need to specify username/password in "connect as".

If that doesn't solve the problem, you can try collect Process Monitor logs to get more information about the error.